# ReactJs | axios.request doesn't await

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I created this reactjs app.

In this app there is a singleton class "ServerMgr" that I use to send post request to my server.

Previously I used the js fetch function and it worked fine, but now I need to replace it with axios.

I replaced it but even if I set the async/await, it doesn't wait for the await.

I explain the situation:
in App.js there is this useEffect triggered when the component is mounted that after creating the ServerMgr singleton, call the function getServerMgr().getFullData().

The function getFullData() is an async function that should await the function requestFetchData() to receive the data from the axios request before returning.

The problem is that getFullData() doesn't await and go ahead without receiveing the request response so the variable appointmentsResults in the useEffect is undefined.

Using the debugger I confirmed that the axios request is correct because it receives the correct data in the .then but after getFullData() went on.

Can you help me?

Here the code:

ServerMgr

```
 serverMgr.requestFetchData = async (service, args) => {

    let data = args
                ?
                JSON.stringify({
                    "service": service,
                    ...args 
                })
                :
                JSON.stringify({
                    "service": service
                })

    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: my_php_script_url,
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data : data
    };

    axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR requestFetchData: " + error);
    });
  }

serverMgr.getFullData = async (cb) => {
    let result = await serverMgr.requestFetchData("getAll")
    if(cb) {
        console.log("getFullData: " + result)
        cb(result)
    }
    else {
        console.log("getFullData: " + result)
        return result
    }
}
```

App.js

```
 useEffect(() => {
    initSingleton() //this load the singleton
    .then(async () => {
      let appointmentsResults = await getServerMgr().getFullData()
      let appointmentsListClean = removeEmptyAppointments(appointmentsResults)
    })
  }, [])  

  const removeEmptyAppointments = (appoArray) => {
    return appoArray.filter((item) => (item.appointment_id ? true : false))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `requestFetchData()` is not returning anything, so it returns a Promise with result `undefined`. You have to return the `axios` response.

```
 serverMgr.requestFetchData = async (service, args) => {

    let data = args
                ?
                JSON.stringify({
                    "service": service,
                    ...args 
                })
                :
                JSON.stringify({
                    "service": service
                })

    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        maxBodyLength: Infinity,
        url: my_php_script_url,
        headers: { 
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        data : data
    };

    return axios.request(config) // here return axios response
    .then((response) => {
        return response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("ERROR requestFetchData: " + error);
    });
  }
```

The code actually returns the `axios` Promise and, since you are not awaiting for anything in you method, `requestFetchData()` could be a "sync" function.

You could also wait for the `axios` response by doing `return await axios.request(config)`, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `await` axios in the `requestFetchData`  ? You use `async` function but you didn't put any `await`, maybe this is a problem ?